# What do multiple deletes mean in docker image rm output?

Tags: docker

I have searched for an answer to my question, but could not find anything in documentation or community. I'm trying to understand why more than one item is deleted when I delete a Docker image by ID. What are the hashes in all the delete lines referring to?

```
$ docker image rm 7cd2d5d6a835
Untagged: blah_blah:latest
Deleted: sha256:7cd2d5d6a835541fc3206bcdea8fb4a65934eb99ac078321447d95e3f78d793e
Deleted: sha256:cfb26f10c5e3e0535338fbb4b0bfa7d55376ea393c93983461b8dd3fd4d277b5
Deleted: sha256:f8a0dbd707b83265ec5dae3c771da808669861be95f07f05964745cbcb3aba32
Deleted: sha256:d712dd2bffc6cd00b726c773cca4bd95da4163118e239f03f5db8dcc15f47048
Deleted: sha256:97a7187e7abc9f0d6e6a1b2825209f3ff98a7ee3329b38d20c2b0877e27fd1f4
Deleted: sha256:9f395669a83234b6a06de72a61e62c486bc7e5152486f5dda74a76b5106f62a1
Deleted: sha256:b70ba9a8844ae03155aa7b55df4e863cd87fe44da924dffff5eaf4d096afa3c6
Deleted: sha256:444f610fa64da322e0fce1faf1274cc6309523237cd846a7e077b8df39c3df24
Deleted: sha256:4422a6c3aac2cd4d0701438e882c43340d24ec89df36d781d4ac99df18491939
Deleted: sha256:09a7046a37b8f863bee75125b96ec2952ed57e68053056ad4e9525174835ffe0
Deleted: sha256:fae2b9323b65aab85790c0e6861d59d751d60ea0a5c01f1b4fc2d69553f00860
Deleted: sha256:87bb1db8cbb6739fd9a56128a00763136eb09a9e1752f86d7e29ef4384f1d09f
Deleted: sha256:fdb7f0ac71c8e3262f3727144fe5ff65e859d92133d8eb8b22d9a6a9b07eaff6
Deleted: sha256:17abb492ca09bdc6ec3b48205c7be671ee1b25aa1ec159312114537439bdc39e
Deleted: sha256:c599e264d9fb3cd929ff9adb5f50261c53447bbe64172ff9ab44050f9719868a
Deleted: sha256:a1ce0c7cf4352d74d4b7cb9bbb9f930a8760e6abab2aca0b31b4179875441758
$
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try using "rmi" instead of "rm"

The docker image rm command "Remove one or more containers" not container image. to check for container and its ID "docker ps -a" command

However, the docker rmi command means rm = remove i = image. it is used to removing docker images. remembers that containers are created from images. the "docker images or docker image ls" shows images, repository, TAG, and image ID. docker rmi <image_ID> to remove image. NOTE even when it is possible to create a new image from the existing image using the "docker commit" command, such image will come it its unique image id.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your response does not answer my question. I did not ask to be told what command to use. I asked what the output means. docker rm and docker image rm are different. My understanding is that docker image rm is equivalent to docker rmi, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I believe the hashes in the delete lines are for the layers of the image, but I'm not certain on that yet.